# Recording and Duplicating a webcam stream with VLC

Tags: stream, vlc, quotes, apostrophe

i'm trying to record a webcam, save it and stream it to a local network.
The Problem is, i want to do this with different compression:
The stream for the local network should only have <400kbit/s, but the other one, which is stored to a local file, should be uncompressed or with up to 10 Mbit/s

So i tried two methods to solve this:

First i played a little bit with the VLC Gui. It is really easy to record the Webcam, then transcode it and save it to a file or/and stream it to the internet. The command line looks like this:

```
vlc v4l2:///dev/video0 :v4l2-standard= :live-caching=300 :sout="#transcode{vcodec=WMV2,vb=380,fps=1,scale=Automatisch,acodec=none}:duplicate{dst=file{dst=stream.asf,no-overwrite},dst=http{dst=:8080/stream.wmv}}" :sout-keep
```

But i had the problem that both, the internet stream and the file, are getting compressed. So i changed the order of "duplicate" and "transcode" to:

```
vlc v4l2:///dev/video0 :v4l2-standard= :live-caching=300 :sout="#duplicate{dst=file{dst=stream.asf,no-overwrite}, dst="transcode{vcodec=WMV2,vb=380,fps=1,scale=Automatisch,acodec=none}:http{dst=:8080/stream.wmv}"}" :sout-keep
```

My thought: Now i should have a compressed internet stream and the orignal file. But it doesn't stream it to the internet.

So i tried another method: I wanted to stream the original stream to port 8080 and then use two other VLC instances to generate a compressed network  stream to port 8008 and a original file. But i cant stream a stream....

So i would be really thankful, if someone has another idea or a hint where my problem is.
Sorry for my english.
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are double quoting the `:sout`. If you plan to use quotes `"` inside the value then use apostrophe `'` to enclose the whole argument like:

`:sout='#duplicate{dst=file{...}, dst="transcode{...}:http{dst=:8080/stream.wmv}"}'`

If you add a `-v` (verbose output) at the end of your command you'll see some other issues too like `no-overwrite` not being recognized. Also,`scale=Automatisch` should be `scale=auto`.

Please note that I checked just the syntax and not your encoding parameters.

Comment: Thanks aergistal :) It works perfectly. I didn't take care of that. Dumb. But thanks again :)